# Serialize method of sortable returns nothing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, serialization, jquery-ui-sortable

Why is my `data` object empty after I've changed the sort order? In the UI the order is changed, but now I want to capture the new order of elements, based on the `id` attributes of the `li` elements.

```
    $(function () {
        $("#sortable").sortable({
            placeholder: "picplaceholder",
            update: function (event, ui) {
                var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        $("#sortable").disableSelection();
    });


    <ul id="sortable">
        <li id="1">
            <div class="editphoto">
                1
                <i class="fa fa-arrows fa-lg pointer"></i>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="2">
            <div class="editphoto">
                2
                <i class="fa fa-arrows fa-lg pointer"></i>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="3">
            <div class="editphoto">
                3
                <i class="fa fa-arrows fa-lg pointer"></i>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***[document says](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize)*** that for serialize to work the `id` should be of a certain format.

> Note: If serialize returns an empty string, make sure the id
>   attributes include an underscore. They must be in the form:
>   "set_number" For example, a 3 element list with id attributes "foo_1",
>   "foo_5", "foo_2" will serialize to "foo[]=1&foo[]=5&foo[]=2". You can
>   use an underscore, equal sign or hyphen to separate the set and
>   number. For example "foo=1", "foo-1", and "foo_1" all serialize to
>   "foo[]=1".

In your case probably the `Id` should be like `id_1` and so on. (I'm just guessing as the question doesn't state about what output is expected out of serialize).

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/UAcC7/1446/)

In case the expected output is an array ( like this ["1", "2", "3"] ) then [`.toArray()`](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray) is a better option

Hope this helps